# Using SQL in Java to set values

Tags: java, sql

Beginner's question: I'm trying to manipulate *tuples* from two different attributes in a relation using Java to process the SQL (for a university non-assessed practical).
I have a relation with four attributes, including the name of a type of coffee, the sales it has that week and the total sales of the coffee.

The code I am trying to create will update the sales and the total fields with new figures. It is meant to take both `totalSales` and `Sales` arrays, add them, then update both attributes in the relation accordingly.

This is my code so far (I've cut out all obvious/unnecessary code):

```
String updateTotalString = "update COFFEES set TOTAL = ? set SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";

String [] coffees = {"Columbian", "Earl Grey", "Kenyan", "Nescafe"};
int [] totalSales = {400,650,340,1000};
int[] sales = {50,75,100,100};

updateTotal = con.prepareStatement(updateTotalString);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        updateTotal.setInt(1, (sales[i] + totalSales[i]));
        updateTotal.setInt(2, sales[i]);
        updateTotal.setString(3, coffees[i]);
        updateTotal.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Unfortunately, running this gives me an SQL syntax error, focusing on the first line (the `String updateTotalString`). I have a feeling it's to do with the fact I'm trying to do two sets in one line and have got the syntax wrong.
Can anybody help me out?

Comment: as a side note; your SQL capitalisation is all backwards, table and field names are usually lowercase, while SQL keywords are usually uppercase.

Comment: @lynks: Thanks for the advice. I was using the Java syntax (which I THINK uses small first letter then capitals for new words when declaring methods. Hadn't even thought about SQL capitalisation. Thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `,` instead of multiple `SET`

```
String updateTotalString = "update COFFEES set TOTAL = ?, SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
```

the basic syntax of update is

```
UPDATE tableName
SET colA = '',
    colB = '', .....
WHERE ....
```

Comment: Brilliant, very helpful. Knew it was going to be a silly mistake!

Answer (score 1):

```java
String updateTotalString =  "update COFFEES set TOTAL = ? set SALES = ? where "
                            + "COF_NAME = ?";
```

In your query, you have used `set` keyword two times, that is not correct syntax.

Rather you should use a `comma` between multiple values to set.

```java
String updateTotalString = "update COFFEES set TOTAL = ?, SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
```

Comment: answer is probably stolen from the opponent.

Comment: @RomanC.. Yeah, actually world war is going on, and I may die if I don't answer, so I steal. Seriously, what kind of thinking level your kind of people have.. And please check the timestamp of this answer and the others, and think of it, whether you can steal in such a small time period.

Answer (score 1):

your syntax for Update is wrong:

```
UPDATE `tableName`
SET
`col1` = ?,
`col2` = ?
WHERE somecondition;
```

check [MYSQL UPDATE SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your update string should be like:

```
String updateTotalString = "update COFFEES set TOTAL = ?, SALES = ? where COF_NAME = ?";
```